# Any Way to Detect Micro Delays using EWS?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am encountering some very long response times from Exchange Online called via the EWS Managed API 2.0 in C#.  I suspect I am being throttled, but I cannot find anything that lets me prove this in the Admin portal for my O365 account.  I have seen in some search results that using PowerShell you can see messages indicating "micro delays" have been applied, but I'm stuck in C#/EWS, so my question is: is there anything I can look at coming back in the responses to my EWS calls that can identify if these micro delays have been applied?  BTW, response times are very close to the 100 second timeout time, which is killing my code.
Thx,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

100 Seconds ins't a micro delay, micro-delays are milliseconds(capped at 500 ms) and are more aimed at delaying a large volume of requests. (eg if an app is going to may 100 sequential requests a microdelay would spread the load of those request out over a greater time by punishing the app more and more and that would lower the resource load on the server). One request taking 100 seconds to fulfill is probably more to do with the request itself. Eg overuse of search filters or overcomplex search etc which my also impact throttling or if your using batching each request withing the batch could have a micro-delay applied.

EWS doesn't return metrics of throttle usage (the new REST API does give a little more information back in this regards). What you need is access to the EWS logs which has that information. Each Exchange request the EWS Managed API makes has and Client Requestid to help correlate the request to log entry there more detail in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn720380(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I've set all the headers I can, but since I'm talking to O365 on the other end, I've no access to any EWS logs, without a support call anyway, a path I've started to explore, so far without much luck. BTW, the call that seems to be getting the most consistent delays is OpenStreamingConnections, which really has no volume of return data. Some of my FindAppointments take a while too, but I'm asking for 48 hours of appts from a single calendar, so I don't think it's a volume thing there either.  I appreciate the ref to the client stats thing--maybe that can be help.

Comment: If its OpenStreamingConnections are you doing this for a group of subscriptions ? If your loading up the connections to their max (eg 200 per group) then you might find it better to ease back on that number which may improve performance. For FindAppointments that shouldn't really be that slow, (unless you using an inline load to get more details of the meeting attendees which is a common performance issue with EWS code eg using loadpropertiesforitems would solve that).I would suggest you establish a baseline request eg last 100 items and then compare the time against the views or filters.

Comment: Again, I appreciate the reply.  So--hard to believe--but I've only got about a half-dozen different calendars to watch, and the groups only have one or two subscriptions per connection.  My current theory is related to the DNS settings on the Azure VM I'm running in.  On another VM, there's nowhere near the delays I see for the problem VM.  The difference: good VM uses Azure DHCP DNS server; bad VM has the public Google DNS (8.8.8.8).  FQDNs for O365 resolve to different IPAddrs.  (I hope I'm on the right track!)